# google mock - how to EXPECT_CALL on a variable name i.e. identifier

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I have a function whose call I need to detect i.e.

`EXPECT_CALL(MockClass_obj, target_func());`

The signature is:

`void MockClass::target_func(HANDLE_t handle);`

Argument `handle` is an opaque type and it's a global set in some other function so yes, I will need to stub it.

Here's the problem: inside the function I am testing, I call `MockClass::target_func` with a few different arguments depending on the branches taken:

```
//MockClass inherits Class, call f1() with instance of MockClass
void f1(int a, Class & obj)
{
    switch(a):
    {
    case 0:
        obj.target_func(global_handle_1);
        break;
    case 1:
        obj.target_func(global_handle_2);
        break;
    default:
        obj.target_func(global_handle_3);

    }
}
```

**QUESTION**

How do I do an expect call based on the NAME of the argument? I need to detect which path was taken.

Since all the `global_handle_[x]` variables will be stubbed out i.e. set to arbitrary value, I could set them to `global_handle_<x>=<x>` and then `EXPECT_CALL(MockClass_obj, target_func(<x>));`

I guess that's good enough but to be more robust, ideally I'd like to EXPECT_CALL on a variable name?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking for is basically not possible with C++.  `target_func` is passed its argument by value, so there is no way for it (or the mocked version of it), to know how the value was calculated.  The call could be `obj.target_func(global_handle_1);` or it could be `obj.target_func(global_handle_2 - 1);` (if those expressions happen to have identical value).

I think your best option is to give each global variable a unique value, and then `EXPECT` the correct value.  I would a) space the unique values well apart; b) rely on code reviews to spot people doing arithmetic on handle values.

If `target_fun` took it's argument by reference, then you *might* be able to do an `EXPECT` based on the address of the reference - but I wouldn't bother.